# Ag-grid filter sorting is wrong

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'm using [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) and I have a small issue with numeric filtering:

[image]

As you can see the sorting is going well unless the numbers are 2xxx but it start to be confusing as soon as it reach 3 numbers.

What I do expect is the sorting starting from 500 and go up to 2400+ or the inverse. Maybe I don't know about a special option to add to achieve this, I'm getting crazy trying different options but nothing seems to work. I hope you can help. Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

I reproduced the issue on the original ag-grid example on filtering:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Tn9ZeCH4fmLr2ZHQPivQ?p=preview I just mutated the year values and as you can see it is not sorting as expected.

```
if (r.year === 2008) r.year = 860
if (r.year === 2012) r.year = 920
```

Comment: It seems it is sorting strings instead numbers. Share your code please.

Comment: I can not share a whole project, it is impossible. But I reproduced it here: https://plnkr.co/edit/Tn9ZeCH4fmLr2ZHQPivQ?p=preview Please try to filter on the year column. This is the example from ag-grid mutated by me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason of this is that it sorts data as string, not number. So just add custom sorting into your `comparator` for your `yeat` field:

```
var numberSort = (num1, num2) => {
    return num1 - num2;
  };
var columnDefs = [
    /*The other code is omitted for the brevity*/
    {headerName: "Year", field: "year", width: 90, comparator: numberSort},
    /*The other code is omitted for the brevity*/
];
```

**UPDATE:**

It looks like you need to add `sortable` to `gridoptions`:

```
var gridOptions = {
    defaultColDef: {
        filter: true,
        sortable: true
    },
}
```

Comment: I will try to implement this solution, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Data sorting is changed but now everything looks randomised. Added screenshot in the question.

Comment: It basically remove the sorting on the main column and fails on sorting on the filter. It looks sorted in the plunker example but the sorting in the main column is broken.

Comment: After some extra tweaking I have been able to sort it out, Thanks for your kind help. Regards

Comment: @AyeyeBrazo I am glad that it helped to you!:)